# Ajuda! Como funciona esse select

Tags: sql, select, pl-sql

Me ajudem a entender como isso funciona por favor.

Acontece que eu estou iniciando os estudos em SQL e no `hackerhank` tem um exercício que precisava deste código:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CITY FROM STATION WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(LOWER(CITY), '^[aeiou]') ;
```

Depois de muito esforço e uma pessoa me ajudou, pois eu havia ido até um pouco mais da metade deste `select` e o final na minha cabeça eu sabia o que devia fazer, mas sem o conhecimento técnico fica difícil escrever.

Alguém pode traduzir o que o código esta fazendo, pois assim posso assimilar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `FROM STATION` seleciona os dados da tabela `STATION`;
- `LOWER(CITY)` irá comparar a coluna `CITY` com a letra minúscula;
- `REGEXP_LIKE(..., '^[aeiou]')` compara se iniciam com vogais;
- `DISTINCT` não apresenta resultados duplicados;

Ou seja: Seleciona todas as `CITY` da tabela `STATION`, sem repetição, que iniciem com vogais no nome;

Comment: Muito obrigado pela explicação, a partir daí  eu puder prosseguir nos estudos com o entendimento na documentação oficial.
Thanks